# What is $H^*(P^2(k)\wedge P^2(k); \mathbb{Z}_k)$ where $P^n(k) = S^{n-1} \cup_{k} e^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $P^n(k) = S^{n-1} \cup_{k} e^n$. We have that $H^{q}(P^n(k)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_k$ for $q = n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then we have that $H^{q}(P^n(k); \mathbb{Z}_k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_k$ for $q = n-1, n$ and $0$ otherwise. **My question is: what is $H^*(P^2(k)\wedge P^2(k); \mathbb{Z}_k)$?**

In a paper that I am reading it is claimed that $H^*(P^2(k)\wedge P^2(k); \mathbb{Z}_k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_k \langle1, e_1, e_2\rangle \otimes \mathbb{Z}_k \langle1, e_1, e_2\rangle$ where $H^*(P^2(k); \mathbb{Z}_k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_k \langle1, e_1, e_2\rangle$. This is motivated **by the Kunneth theorem** and the fact that the $\mod k$ cohomology is free. I cannot understand why it is true. In fact:

1. The Kunneth theorem that I know involves cartesian products, not smash products. Moreover, I do not think that $H^*(X \wedge Y; R) \cong H^*(X; R) \otimes H^*(Y; R)$ holds in general, neither if the cohomologies are free: for example this does not work for $X = Y = S^1$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}$.
2. We have the cofibration sequence $S^1 \xrightarrow {k} S^1 \to P^2(k)$, then smashing with $P^2(k)$ we obtain the cofibration sequence $S^1 \wedge P^2(k) \xrightarrow {k} S^1 \wedge P^2(k) \to P^2(k) \wedge P^2(k)$ that is $P^3(k) \xrightarrow {k} P^3(k) \to P^2(k) \wedge P^2(k)$ because $S^1 \wedge P^2(k) \cong P^3(k)$. The long exact sequence $\mod k$ then gives $H^1 \cong 0$, $H^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_k$, $H^3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_k \oplus \mathbb{Z}_k$, $H^4 \cong \mathbb{Z}_k$ and $0$ otherwise. But this is in contradiction with above! For example above we have $H^1 \not\cong 0$!

What's wrong with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Kunneth theorem for smash products is that the reduced cohomology of the smash product is the tensor product of the reduced cohomologies. This follows from the normal Kunneth theorem by noting that the smash product collapses the subspace which provides the $H^* (X) \otimes p$ and $q \otimes H^*(Y)$ part of the cohomology of the product. Here $p,q$ represent the element of the 0th cohomology associated to the basepoints.

Comment: Or just use the formula $(X\times Y)_+=X_+\wedge Y_+$. For the first question, note that 'free' means free over the ground ring $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Not free abelian. Also note that the graded tensor product is used in $H^*X\otimes H^*Y$ and reduced cohomology is meant (so in your example $X=Y=S^1$ you get $X\wedge Y\cong S^2$ and the correct answer).

Comment: Thank you both! Very helpful! I am aware of the meaning of free module and the use of graded tensor product, but I was not aware that the cohomologies have to be intended reduced!

Comment: If I recall you were reading J. Strom's book? If so, then see $\S$21.7 for some relevant discussion.

Comment: @Tyrone Do you really remember me? I thought I was invisible on this site ahaha I used Strom's book to learn homotopy (co)limits, now I am working on my MSc thesis... but I will take a look, thank you!